# No JMX mbeans found of springboot2's embeded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, jmx

We have upgraded our system to springboot2(springboot-2.2.2+ springCloud-Hoxton.RELEASE), and found that there were no any Tomcat related JMX mbeans. Below is what I got when connect to my local application by jvisualvm:

[springboot2-v2.2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2dn1.png)

[springboot2-v2.2.2+jmx-enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDyap.png)

Also I implemented a springboot2(v2.1.1) demo, it was ok, tomcat‘s JMX mbeans works well. The strange thing is there are 2 tomcat.

[springboot-v2.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVEbI.png)

[springboot-v1.5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOKEA.png)

As I have implemented a Endpoint to monitor the thread pool of tomcat, which completely depends on JMX of tomcat, now it doesn't work any more. Please help, is there any way to enable the JMX of tomcat with springboot-v2.2.2?

Answer (score 4):

To enable Tomcat JMX in springboot 2.2 following tomcat customizer must be configured:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> activateTomcatMBeanServer() {

    return (factory) -> {
        factory.setDisableMBeanRegistry(false);
    };
}
```

This has been introduced with [SpringBoot Issue 16498](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16498) and Version 2.2.0.M4. Spring Boot utilizes a new feature of Tomcat 9.0.20 which allows to disable Tomcat’s MBeanServer (org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry. disableRegistry() - Tomcat also uses this switch when Graal is present). The corresponding Tomcat issue is [Tomcat Issue 63361](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63361).

Answer (score 4):

By now, you can simply use

```
server:
  tomcat:
    mbeanregistry:
      enabled: true
```

so as a better spring-boot way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following vm argument for the Mbean not appearing up issue.

```
-Dspring.jmx.enabled=true
```